# Transpose (treating the array) a one dimensional array in java

Tags: java

if i have the following table:

```
int v[] = new int [2];
v[0]=20;
v[1]=35;
```

so i get

```
v= [20 35]
```

Now, i want to transpose the table v in order to obtain:

```
v= [20

    35

    ]
```

but how ?

Best Regards,

Liszt.

Comment: What do you mean by "transpose"?

Comment: It's not a table, it's a vector.

Comment: sorry, i edit now my question :)

Comment: In response to your edited question, it doesn't make sense to do this because an array doesn't correspond to a mathematical vector. Something like `v = {...}` is just syntax.

Comment: that i want is to treating the array as a matrix of 1xN, see the answer of @morgano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're treating the array as a matrix of 1xN, then just create an array per element:

```
int v[] = new int [2];
v[0]=20;
v[1]=35;

// ...

int[][] vT = new int[v.length][1];
for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    vT[i][0] = v[i];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, this code resolves my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int v[] = new int [2];
v[0]=20;
v[1]=35;
```

If you transpose this table (in this case it is a vector), you end up with the same values in the same places. See this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) article. As your own diagram shows, it is how you visualize it and what you take the index to represent.

If you hold your vector in a square matrix, transposition would be more obvious:

```
a b
c d
```

transposes to

```
a c
b d
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double[] arr = new double[] {20, 35};
RealMatrix rm = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(arr);
rm.transpose();
```

Comment: no that i want is to treating the array as a matrix of 1xN, see the answer of @morgano,, anw thank you for your answer :)

Comment: i have a problem with RealMatrix